# python winrt windows Toast notification get input as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, notifications

```
import winrt.windows.ui.notifications as notifications
import winrt.windows.data.xml.dom as dom

#create notifier
nManager = notifications.ToastNotificationManager
notifier = nManager.create_toast_notifier(r"C:\Users\andyy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe")

#define your notification as 

tString = """
<toast>

    <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
            <text>Sample toast</text>
            <text>Sample content</text>
            <text>asdfasdadsfds</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>

    <actions>
        <input id="textBox" type="text" placeHolderContent="Type a reply"/>
        <action
            content="Send"
            arguments="action=reply&amp;convId=9318"
            activationType="background"
            hint-inputId="textBox"/>
    </actions>

</toast>
"""


#convert notification to an XmlDocument
xDoc = dom.XmlDocument()
xDoc.load_xml(tString)

#display notification
notifier.show(notifications.ToastNotification(xDoc))
```

This is my attempt at creating a toast notification with an input, and it works. But I want to get the string that the user enters into the input. How am I supposed to do this?

[image]

Comment: I can't test it but why not to `print(dir(notifier))` and check all avaible methods and properties?

Comment: The thing is, the script ends as soon as I run it.
Also, I tried to `print(dir(notifier))`, and it returns `['__class__', '__delattr__' ...more things... 'setting', 'show', 'update']` and I tried all of them, but nothing seems to be working

Comment: In my case it doesnt even show any notification, how did you get it to work ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register for backgroundaccess [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=xml#buttons)

> Buttons make your toast interactive, letting the user take quick actions on your toast notification without interrupting their current workflow. For example, users can reply to a message directly from within a toast, or delete an email without even opening the email app. Buttons appear in the expanded portion of your notification.

I am trying to register but failed. let me know if it works