# Python change app_name in win10toast

Tags: python

Recently i tried to make a toast notification i used the package [win10toast](https://pypi.org/project/win10toast/).

Then i couldn't get rid of the "Python" app name at the top. If i compile it to an exe it says "yourapp.exe" is there a way to change that this is my code:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast("Test","Test",duration=10)
```

Here is a screenshot of how it looks:

[image]

I hope it is possible because i saw a application written in python that had the website url at the top. If there is no way to do that in [win10toast](https://pypi.org/project/win10toast/) is there a other library that can do that?

Would be amazing if someone could help me <3

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little bit late and you've probably already moved on in your life, but I do know of a new module. My own! ([Win10Toast](https://github.com/MaliciousFiles/Win10Toast)) Unfortunately I haven't added capability to change the name, however you can use the updated version of Microsoft Toasts! It also allows you to put buttons on. You can check out [Microsoft's page to see what can go in the XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=xml) and [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65871197/python-winrt-windows-toast-notification-get-input-as-a-variable) page for how to use that XML in Python with the WinRT module.

I am planning on updating Win10Toast to use the WinRT module, but haven't gotten around to it yet.